# Manually trigger Pull to refresh on Container

Tags: codenameone

If I want to manually trigger Pull to Refresh on Container in Codename One after the load of the form. Please advise if anyone have any idea.

Answer (score 3):

It's easy, the trick is the use of the `showListener`. Suppose that this is the starting code (taken from the Codename One Developer Guide, [section "Pull to refresh"](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/misc-features.html#_pull_to_refresh)):

```
    Form hi = new Form("Pull To Refresh", BoxLayout.y());
    hi.getContentPane().addPullToRefresh(() -> {
        hi.add("Pulled at " + L10NManager.getInstance().formatDateTimeShort(new Date()));
    });
    hi.show();
```

To invoke the "Pull to Refresh" listener after the load of the Form, you can do so:

```
    Form hi = new Form("Pull To Refresh", BoxLayout.y());
    Runnable myRunnable = () -> {
        hi.add("Pulled at " + L10NManager.getInstance().formatDateTimeShort(new Date()));
    };
    hi.getContentPane().addPullToRefresh(() -> {
        myRunnable.run();
    });
    hi.addShowListener(l -> {
        myRunnable.run();
    });
    hi.show();
```

Comment: FYI if you are using `InfiniteContainer` you can use `refresh()`.

Comment: Shai. refresh() method doesn't trigger manual refresh on the container. I want to refresh the container after the load of the form means I should trigger swipe down (refresh) action manually without swiping down the container. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: `pullToRefresh` just invokes a method you can just invoke that method manually as shown by by @francesco-galgani