# how to manually trigger the refresh the container after loading content in InfiniteContainer + codenameone

Tags: codenameone

How to refresh the infinite container after loading the content. Please see the attached code.
I have tried different ways to refresh the container but none of them works. I have tried following post and not able to make it work.
[Manually trigger Pull to refresh on Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183183/manually-trigger-pull-to-refresh-on-container)
if some one can point out where should I change the code to refresh manually that would be great. Please let me know.

```
 class AppointmentsContainerInfinite extends InfiniteContainer {

        private final Server.AppointmentFolders folder;
        private Date currentDate = new Date();
        private Date counterDate = currentDate;        

        public AppointmentsContainerInfinite(boolean includeAccept, boolean includeReject, boolean includeMap, Server.AppointmentFolders folder) {
            this.includeAccept = includeAccept;
            this.includeReject = includeReject;
            this.includeMap = includeMap;
            this.folder = folder;
        } 

       @Override
        public Component[] fetchComponents(int index, int amount) {
            if (index == 0) {
                counterDate = currentDate;
            }
            SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
            final int DAY = 24 * 60 * 60000;
            Date dd = endDate;
            if (endDate == null) {
                dd = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + DAY * Server.instance.getAppointmentDaysPerBatch());
            }
            boolean flg = Server.instance.isOffline();
            Appointment[] apps = Server.instance.fetchAppointments(counterDate, dd, folder);
            ArrayList<Component> response = new ArrayList<>();
            String lastDate = sd.format(counterDate);
            response.add(new Label(lastDate, "Header"));
            if (apps == null || apps.length == 0) {
                if (index == 0) {
                    return new Component[]{new Label("No Appointments", "Header")};
                }
                return null;
            }

            for (Appointment app : apps) {
                String d = sd.format(app.getDate());
                if (!d.equals(lastDate)) {
                    response.add(new Label("No Appointments", "Header1"));
                }
                break;
            }

            for (Appointment a : apps) {
                String d = sd.format(a.getDate());
                if (!d.equals(lastDate)) {
                    SimpleDateFormat sd1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd,yyyy");
                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    Date startDate1 = SITUtil.removeTime(a.getDate());
                    Date endDate1 = SITUtil.removeTime(counterDate);
                    if ((endDate1.getTime() / DAY) + 1 < startDate1.getTime() / DAY) {
                        // add "No Appointments" enteries until the next date...
                        Date temp = new Date(endDate1.getTime() + DAY);
                        while (temp.getTime() / DAY < startDate1.getTime() / DAY) {
                            response.add(new Label(sd.format(temp), "Header"));
                            response.add(new Label("No Appointments", "Header1"));
                            temp = new Date(temp.getTime() + DAY);
                        }

                    }
                    lastDate = d;
                    counterDate = a.getDate();
                    response.add(new Label(lastDate, "Header"));
                }
//                else {
                Image icon;
                if (a.getEndTime() > -1) {
                    if (greenIcon == null) {
                        greenIcon = Image.createImage(iconSize, iconSize, 0xff4caf50);
                    }
                    icon = greenIcon;
                } else {
                    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                    cal1.setTime(a.getDate());
                    yellowIcon = Image.createImage(iconSize, iconSize, ColorUtil.rgb(255, 140, 0));
                    icon = yellowIcon;
                    }  

                }
                String endOrDuration;
                if (a.getEndTime() > -1) {
                    endOrDuration = "End: " + SITUtil.formatTime(a.getEndTime());
                } else if (Server.instance.isShownField("DurationInMinutesForAppointmentDetailsForMobile")) {
                    endOrDuration = "Duration: " + a.getDurationMinutes() + " Mins";

                } else {
                    endOrDuration = "Duration: " + SITUtil.formatDuration(a.getDurationMinutes());
                }
                SmartButton appointmentButton = new SmartButton(a.getAppointmentNumber(),
                        icon,
                        "Start: " + SITUtil.formatTime(a.getStartTime()),
                        endOrDuration);
                if (Server.instance.isOffline()) {
                    Style s = appointmentButton.getRightComponent().getAllStyles();
                    s.setBgTransparency(255);
                    s.setBgColor(0xFFFF00);
                }
                appointmentButton.addActionListener(e -> new AppointmentForm(a, includeAccept, includeReject, includeMap).show());
                response.add(appointmentButton);
//                }
            }
            counterDate = new Date(counterDate.getTime() + DAY);
            return response.toArray(new Component[response.size()]);
        }
    }

        public AppointmentsForm(boolean includeAccept, boolean includeReject, boolean includeMap, Server.AppointmentFolders folder) {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        if (Display.getInstance().isTablet()) {
            hText = 6.5f;
        }
        for (MenuOptions m : MenuOptions.values()) {
            if ((m.getName().toLowerCase().indexOf(folder.toString().toLowerCase())) >= 0) {
                this.setTitle(m.getTitle());
            }
        }
        boolean flg1 = Server.instance.isOffline();
        AppointmentsContainerInfinite appointmentsContainer = new AppointmentsContainerInfinite(includeAccept, includeReject, includeMap, folder);
        SITUtil.addDateRange(this, (s, e) -> appointmentsContainer.setRange(s, e));
        SITUtil.addSideMenu(this);
        appointmentsContainer.setScrollableY(true);
        appointmentsContainer.refreshTheme();
//        getContentPane().
        content.revalidate();
        content.add(BorderLayout.CENTER, appointmentsContainer);
        if (folder.equals(Server.AppointmentFolders.APPOINTMENTS)) {
            Button startActivityAppt = new Button("Start");
            FontImage.setMaterialIcon(startActivityAppt, FontImage.MATERIAL_ASSIGNMENT, hText);
            SITUtil.makeBorderRound(startActivityAppt);
            content.add(BorderLayout.SOUTH, startActivityAppt);
            startActivityAppt.addActionListener(e -> {
                new ActivityForm(null).show();
            });
        }

//        content.repaint();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `refresh()` will clear the content of the container and call `fetchComponents()` over again.

Because your code also has state you will probably also need to do this:

```
counterDate = currentDate;
```